# FFmpeg not utilizing all the threads properly for transcoding as it used to

Tags: cpu, ffmpeg, cpu-usage

As I heard about FFmpeg and found it more efficient to Transcode videos, so I started using it for doing 90% transcoding my videos into h.265 for decreasing file size. I installed it and I just started working with it. FFmpeg struggled to utilize all the threads with 1080p or lower resolution files, so what I did was that I started transcoding videos in parallel, meaning doing the simultaneous transcoding in 3 different command windows, which worked perfectly utilizing the thread up to 99%-100%.

For some booting issues that my system had, I had to do a complete new windows 10 install. and by that, after re installing FFMpeg, and running the very same bat file a created for transcoding a folder (simultaneous transcoding), it uses the threads in very inefficient way, by capping 16 of them and not the rest.

You can see them here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2j0k.jpg

Hardware wise, I am using the very same system as before. I just removed 1x8GB RAM stick out of it, to use on another system. I have 24GB of RAM at the moment, But I don't assume that's the issue.

I asked this question here, because the most of the things I learned about ffmpeg was from here. I'm no expert coder by any means, but I want to know if I missed something.

imgur.com/a/ZzG1S

`for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -c:v libx265 -x265-params crf=26 -c:a copy "newfiles\%%~na.mp4" pause`

this is saved in bat file.

Thanks

Comment: Show your full command.

Comment: Here you go:
https://imgur.com/a/ZzG1S
------
`for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -c:v libx265 -x265-params crf=26 -c:a copy "newfiles\%%~na.mp4"
pause`
this is saved in bat file.

Comment: That doesn't show multiple transcoding

Comment: I know, I have 3 bat files like this in 3 separate folders, and then I will initiate all 3 of them, and it'll do the job.